# Sort collection after associated resource's acts_as_tree/acts_as_list order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, has-many, acts-as-list, acts-as-tree

I have a `SuccessCriterion` model that implements both `acts_as_tree` and `acts_as_list` so it can be arranged as sorted tree hierarchy. Every success criterion can has many `Boilerplate` objects.

```
class SuccessCriterion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boilerplates

  acts_as_tree order: :position, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  acts_as_list scope: [:parent_id]
end

class Boilerplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :success_criterion
end
```

I can retrieve an flat array of all the success criteria sorted correctly by calling `SuccessCriterion.collection_tree`.

Now when listing the boilerplates, I want them ordered by the hierarchy of the success criteria. What's the easiest way to do this? I think I have to manually sort the collection using Ruby, but I'm unsure how to do it.

**Update**

My first try is the following, but it feels a bit clumsy:

```
def index
  # @boilerplates is provided by ransack

  ordered_boilerplates = []

  SuccessCriterion.collection_tree.each do |success_criterion|
    ordered_boilerplates += @boilerplates.select do |boilerplate|
      boilerplate.success_criterion_id == success_criterion.id
    end
  end

  ordered_boilerplates += @boilerplates.select do |boilerplate|
    boilerplate.success_criterion_id.nil?
  end

  @boilerplates = ordered_boilerplates
end
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `act_as_tree`, but the [source documentation](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree/blob/master/lib/acts_as_tree.rb#L59) mentions that the `order` attribute *makes it possible to sort the children according to this SQL snippet.* Might be worth investigating.